# Log4J 1.2 Micrometer metrics

Tags: micrometer

It seems that micrometer metrics is available only for Log4J2 and Logback.
But there is not metrics for Log4J 1.2.
Is there any simple way to get log4j 1.2 integration for micrometer metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an appender that records counts.

DropWizard has an [InstrumentedAppender](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/release/4.1.x/metrics-log4j2/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/log4j2/InstrumentedAppender.java) that you could mimic. Here is a usage example: https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/log4j.html